# How to get the source code from a last successful build

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was wondering if there was a way that I could snag the source code from the last successful build of a C# project in visual studio. The last build works just fine when I run it, but the current code doesn't work at all. Any way to do this?

Comment: You should use source control.

Comment: The size of that last comment does not make justice of its value, so here's repeated: *You should use source control*. Now repeat that 100 times.

Comment: again, use source control. It will not only provide you with the previous version, but a complete history, also it allows multiple developers to work collaboratively on the same project..... don't forget, use source control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you build your solution, the source file in your `"Visual Studio / Projects / Your project / Your project"` folder will be created (or overwritten) with a .cs extension. If you want to get the code as a string, you could simply run your app and use a `StremReader` object to do the work.

```
//...
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(/*the source path*/);
txtSourceCode.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
sr.Dispose();
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any central code repository (VSS, SVN etc) then you can see this link for more information on how to decomile a dll. 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/05b3cf5d-ead3-4274-88f5-6e8cbda8e8d8/decompiling-a-dll-file-to-view-source-code?forum=msbuild

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Reflection tool.  Some options are:

http://ilspy.net/

http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Answer (score 0):

use a decompiler on the working dll, for example http://www.ilspy.net/
It may not be exactly the same but it should be close enough to give you insight